# What is a good way to find real time in milliseconds with C++?

Tags: c++, linux, datetime, time

I am currently using `clock()` function supplied by the `time.h` library. It gives me time precision up to milliseconds. However, it's timing is based on CPU clock cycles. I need a function that instead of using CPU cycles as `clock()`, will use system realtime with precision up to milliseconds.

I am using linux with gcc compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#include <sys/time.h>

...

timeval tv;
gettimeofday (&tv, NULL);
return double (tv.tv_sec) + 0.000001 * tv.tv_usec;
```

Answer (score 3):

Linux (and POSIX.1-2001) provides [`gettimeofday()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) to get current time to microsecond precision.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`clock_gettime(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html).

Answer (score 0):

> CLOCK_REALTIME

gives nanoseconds. Go no further, You might start a space-warp. :)